# Setting JFormattedTextField to take only allowed values

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jformattedtextfield

How do I create a `JFormattedTextField` that only takes in a set of numbers and will not allow the user to type in letters or any other characters besides 0123456789?

Comment: DocumentFilter, but NumberFormatter seems like as good for ... (accepts decimal separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you have to create your custom KeyListener
following code will show you how you can achieve this

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
@Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char c = e.getKeyChar();

        if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            e.consume();
        }
    }
```